# This NSLayoutConstraint is being configured with a constant that exceeds internal limits. In Google Maps Custom Info Window

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, nslayoutconstraint, gmsmapview

When I am trying to add a custom info window to google map's GMSMarker, then I am getting following error:

```
This NSLayoutConstraint is being configured with a constant that exceeds internal limits.  A smaller value will be substituted, but this problem should be fixed. Break on BOOL _NSLayoutConstraintNumberExceedsLimit(void) to debug.  This will be logged only once.  This may break in the future.
```

This error occurs only when I put autolayout constraints to label in the view xib file. If no constraints then the info window appears good.

I am using xCode Version 9.1 (9B55)

Any help is appreciated.